# How can I call a function within a login() function - python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a login function already which I would like to use in the code to call other functions.

```
def login():
    while True:
        loginUser = input("Username: ")
        loginPass = getpass.getpass()
        for user_info in users:
            if loginUser == user_info[0] and loginPass == user_info[1]:
                print("Success\n")
                return
        else:
            print("Wrong username or password\n")
```

Is there a way so that after it prints 'Success' I can call a function without putting it IN the login() function or just rewriting out the entire block of code again for example

```
login()
if login() is successful then function()
else print wrong username
```

rather than just adding the whole function to another function or adding the function under the success part.

Comment: Have your `login` function return `True`/`False`, and act on that…?!

Comment: Really, you need to go through a tutorial, which will explain how to call functions, how to turn values from then etc. There is to much knowledge you are missing to be said on one answer, but following a tutorial will help you learn this and more in the most efficient way.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still learning and didn't actually know what the return function does so this helps a ton,

Comment: zvone I definitely will do that thanks

Comment: As written, your `login` function can *only* succeed. The only way to break out of the infinite loop is to get the password right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a simple `return`, you can `return True` if success, and `return False` if not

```py
def login():
    while True:
        loginUser = input("Username: ")
        loginPass = getpass.getpass()
        for user_info in users:
            if loginUser == user_info[0] and loginPass == user_info[1]:
                print("Success\n")
                return True
        else:
            print("Wrong username or password\n")
            return False
```

Then using it:

```py
if login():
    success_function()
```

Comment: The `while` loop isn't needed in your solution, as the `for` loop will always reach one of the two `return` statements.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. However, I would like to change the op's code as little as possible. I should pointed that out, though.